# Android: How to have the remove the previous value pressed through custom key board

Tags: java, android

I making own keyboard for android and I want have control over the values pressed through custom keyboard, for example when I press 'c' and the press 'h', then instead of writing ch on the text field I want to replace the c or both ch with other letter in other language.
thank you

Comment: Here is excellent tutorial on creating custom keyboard in android, give it try first. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615

Comment: @mumair bhai, I went through the tutorial that you are recommending and actually I made the keyboard through that but I need some modification to have control over the words I'm printing